# Aggregation pipeline to change data structure in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a mongodb database with the following structure

```
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("56f1492e95136b7d113dd1c7"),   
"name" : "Terminal 1 Sample Port",
"owl" : [ 
    {
        "macId" : "443A3",
        "hostName" : "Old",
        "group" : "High Mast Lighting",
        "subGroup" : "Public Marshalling Area"
    }, 
    {
        "macId" : "4437",
        "hostName" : "LED Mast 7",
        "group" : "High Mast Lighting",
        "subGroup" : "Public Marshalling Area"
    },
   {
        "macId" : "4437190",
        "hostName" : "Ground Floor",
        "group" : "Terminal 1",
        "subGroup" : "Ground Floor"
    }, 
    {
        "macId" : "44387",
        "hostName" : "LED 80mt ",
        "group" : "High Mast Lighting",
        "subGroup" : "Commercial Goods Area"
    },
]
```

}

which I want to convert to the following structure

```
 [
        { "name": "High Mast Lighting", 
          "subvalues": [{ 
                            "name": "Public Marshalling Area", 
                            "subvalues": 
                                        [{ "id": "44373",                              
                                            "name": "Old  3"
                                        }, 
                                        {  "id": "443778", 
                                           "name": "LED Light Mast 7"
                                        }]
                     }]
        }
]
```

I have been able to do the same using lodash but I want to know if the same can be achieved using mongodb aggregation framework

Comment: Yes, of course it can, though just through an intermediate collection using the `$out` stage. If you want to do it, you should probably show us what you tried so far.

Comment: If indeed you are "changing the structure" then aggregation is not the correct tool for this. Whilst you can use `$out` to write to a collection, it is a "new" collection which will be different to the existing source. If you are just "tranforming" an existing source and intend to keep the collection, then looping the data and using "Bulk Writes" is the better option for this case. But I would also strongly discourage your intended output format, since "nested arrays" are not a wise idea due to the constraints on atomically updating the data.

Comment: My intention is to keep the collection, the output is only to be used for generating menus.

Answer (score 0):

you need to play with that - but as an output you will get what you want:

```
db.a.aggregate([
{$unwind:"$owl"},
{$group: {
    _id:{"name":"$owl.group", "subvaluesName":"$owl.subGroup" },
     subvalues1: { $addToSet:{ "id": "$owl.macId" , "name":"$owl.hostName"}}   
     }},

   {
       $project:{
           _id:0,
           name:"$_id.name",
           subvalues:{
               name:"$_id.subvaluesName",
               subvalues:"$subvalues1"
               }
           }}
])
```

> output:

```
{
    "name" : "High Mast Lighting",
    "subvalues" : {
        "name" : "Public Marshalling Area",
        "subvalues" : [ 
            {
                "id" : "443A3",
                "name" : "Old"
            }, 
            {
                "id" : "4437",
                "name" : "LED Mast 7"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

and to persist changes use $out as last aggregation stage.